# Script only works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently started to learn jQuery so I had some exercices to do. This one is about displaying messages by clicking on page element. Here is the code :

```js
var $caption = $('caption');

$caption.on('click', function(event) {

    $(' <td>Wp it worked</td>').insertAfter('tr');

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>

        <head>

            <title>Happy Birthday !</title>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

            <meta charset="utf-8">

        </head>

        <body>

                <table>

                    <caption>Click here</caption>

                        <tr>

 

                        </tr>

                </table>

        </body>

    </html>
```

So the problem is that it doesn't work. When I write the script in the console it works perfectly, but with the js file it basicly doesn't. So I know it's not a problem of folder because when I put something like alert('test'); in the js file it works. Someone knows why ?

Comment: Move the `script` tag to the end of `<body>` element or wrap the code in `ready()` as shown in the answers of the linked question.

Comment: It is working perfectly in the snippet that you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is working in the snippet , however you may try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var $caption = $('caption');

        $caption.on('click', function (event) {

            $(' <td>Wp it worked</td>').insertAfter('tr');

        });
    });
```

Comment: I basically moved the <script> tag at the end of the html document and it works, thanks

Comment: Enclosing the code inside document.ready ensures that it doesn't execute before the page is fully rendered.